# Change location of Docker Registry inside Kubernetes Pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am novice to Kubernetes. Recently my Docker registry url is changed from `dockerhub.abc.com` to `dockerhub.def.com`. Is it possible that i can change this in properties of Kubernetes pod so that next time,it pulls from new registry?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using secrets to hold your authorization token for your Docker registry, you can refer to [using private registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-in-the-cluster-that-holds-your-authorization-token)

I recommend you to use secrets. All you need to do is create a new secret or update the existing one with your new url, and then put this secret to your Pod's .yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: <your-secret-name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.Can I know the location of yaml file inside pod ?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, yaml files are stored in your machine just like all the other regular files. You can create them wherever you want. So if you want to find a specific yaml file of a pod, then you need to search it in your machine.

Comment: Also you can display the details of a Pod in yaml format using

`kubectl get pod your-pod-name -o=yaml`

Answer (score 1):

In general you'll find it easiest if you explicitly qualify your image names to include the repository name, and not depend on a default value that isn't the official Docker Hub

```
image: dockerhub.abc.com/dist/image:1.2.3
```

in which case you can just change the image name in your deployment

```
image: dockerhub.def.com/dist/image:1.2.3
```

If you're using a system like [Helm](https://helm.sh/) to manage your Kubernetes manifests, you might find it helpful to include the image base name and/or repository in its values file

```
image: dockerhub.abc.com/dist/image
tag: 1.2.3

image: {{ printf "%s:%s" .Values.image .Values.tag }}
```

and then you can just change the image's repository location and redeploy.